Problemas con scroll de pagina
tengo problemas con el scroll de este codigo, encuentra bien la primera variable y luego no hace nada, esto es por que el resto de la informacion esta mas abajo, funciona perfecto si hago scroll manual pero necesito que simplmeente lo haga automatico
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver_path = xxxx


service = Service(executable_path=driver_path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

url = 'https://app.racional.cl/asset-details/AA'

driver.get(url)

try:
    precio_accion_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//p[@class="asset-price"]/app-animated-number'))
    )
    precio_accion = precio_accion_element.text.strip()
    print("Precio de la acción en dólares:", precio_accion)

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight / 2);")

    time.sleep(2)

    tasa_dividendos_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "share asset-property") and .//h5[text()="Tasa de dividendos"]]//p[@class="asset-property-value statistics-value"]'))
    )


    tasa_dividendos = tasa_dividendos_element.text.strip()
    print("Tasa de dividendos:", tasa_dividendos)


    ebitda_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "share asset-property") and .//h5[text()="EBITDA"]]//p[@class="asset-property-value statistics-value"]'))
    )


    ebitda = ebitda_element.text.strip()
    print("EBITDA:", ebitda)

    pe_ratio_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "share asset-property") and .//h5[text()="Ratio P/E"]]//p[@class="asset-property-value statistics-value"]'))
    )
    pe_ratio = pe_ratio_element.text.strip()
    print("Ratio P/E:", pe_ratio)

    market_cap_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "share asset-property") and .//h5[text()="Capitalización de mercado"]]//p[@class="asset-property-value statistics-value"]'))
    )

    market_cap = market_cap_element.text.strip()
    print("Capitalización de mercado:", market_cap)

finally:
    driver.quit()

si lo hago manual funciona perfecto, porfavor ayuda he intentado de todo

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! que tenia que ver java con esto???

Java y Javascript son dos lenguajes diferentes. Si crees que tu problema tiene relación con el javascript involucrado en tu código, podrías agregar la etiqueta correspondiente. Además, estaría bueno que mejorases la pregunta en lugar de colocar ruido para poder publicar. Por ejemplo: en lugar de "he intentado de todo", podrías explicar al menos una de las cosas que hayas intentado. Eso nos evitará tratar de recomendarte lo que ya probaste y servirá como evidencia de que intentaste algo y no parecerás alguien que no pone voluntad.

Por cierto, si es que no intentaste esto, podrías colocar tu código de scroll en la consola del navegador para ver si el problema está en Python o JS
